# Adding order by for XML throws error

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my actual query

```
SELECT 
    aces.ProductID,'<p>' +  
    Replace(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(A.year AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + A.make + ' ' + A.model + ' ' + A.enginebase_new 
                   FROM ACES_Data A 
                   WHERE A.ProductID = aces.ProductID 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), ',', '<br>')
           + '</p><p>' + i.[Subline Code] + '<br>' + i.[Subline Name] + '</p>' AS FullDescription 
FROM
    ACES_Data aces 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InventoryPricing i ON aces.part_number = i.PART  
WHERE 
    aces.ProductID IS NOT NULL
    AND aces.MakeModelMappingID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    aces.ProductID, i.[Part Description], i.[Subline Code], i.[Subline Name]
```

Now adding order by before XML throws an error.

Please look below updated query

```
 SELECT 
    aces.ProductID,'<p>' +  
    Replace(
            STUFF
                (
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            distinct ', ' + Cast(A.year as varchar(4)) + ' ' + A.make +' ' + A.model + ' ' + A.enginebase_new 
                        FROM 
                            ACES_Data A 
                        Where 
                            A.ProductID=aces.ProductID 
                        order by A.make,A.year asc
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                    ),1,1,'')
                    ,',',
                    '<br>'
                )
    + '</p><p>' + i.[Subline Code] + '<br>'+ i.[Subline Name] + '</p>' As FullDescription 
from ACES_Data aces 
Left outer join InventoryPricing i 
on aces.part_number = i.PART  
where aces.ProductID is not null 
and aces.MakeModelMappingID is not null  
Group By aces.ProductID,i.[Part Description],i.[Subline Code],i.[Subline Name]
```

on inserting

```
Where A.ProductID=aces.ProductID **order by A.make,A.year asc**  FOR XML PATH('')
```

it gives me error as

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: You are not using MySQL, Oracle , *and* SQL Server. Please only add the tag for the RDMS you are actually using.

Comment: You should also format your query because most users here are not interested in reading a long string like that

Comment: I formatted as of now your query but please make in future you format your query always on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `enginebase_new` & `model` is not part of `Order by` you cannot use `DISTINCT` in `Select`.

Use `Group by` instead of `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates

```
SELECT ', ' + Cast(A.year AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + A.make
       + ' ' + A.model + ' ' + A.enginebase_new
FROM   ACES_Data A
WHERE  A.ProductID = aces.ProductID
GROUP  BY A.year,
          A.make,
          A.model,
          A.enginebase_new
ORDER  BY A.make,
          A.year ASC
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: showing error as Column 'ACES_Data.year' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: on removing +' '+ form query i m facing issue as "Column 'ACES_Data.make' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: what about second issue i m facing?"Column 'ACES_Data.make' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @Xtremcool - Run this query alone and check first.. dont replace in your query

Comment: actually issue is coming only for year and not for make

Comment: @Xtremcool - What is the datatype of `year` what information is stored in it ?